# Adding Branches to SQL Server Projects in TFS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, sql-server-2012

I created a project in `SQL Server 2012` and added it to source control. That works fine. I launched `visual studio`, open team explorer and created a branch from my main project. I mapped that branch to a separate folder and downloaded the files. When I try to open my project in `SQL Server Management Studio`, I getting a binding error. So I had to choose to manually change the bindings and connections for it to work. When I merge my branch with main, I have to go again and reset the bindings. Am I doing something wrong? How can I avoid this issue? Can I do branches in SQL Server Projects?

[image]

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you mean you created a project from SSMS and checked in to TFS?

Comment: Is there MSSCCPRJ.SCC file? If so, update the collections manually instead of GUI by editing that file, then check in. More information: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/source-control-unable-to-access-database/

Answer (score 0):

I've tested to create a a project from SSMS and checked in to TFS 2013 with TFS MSSCCI Provider, after creating a branch and open it, I'll only get the warning below, not as yours. In my test, I just need to select the checkbox to avoid this warning:

[image]

Comment: How did you create the branch? Via Visual studio, team explorer?

Comment: Yes, I created the branch in Team Explorer. Which version of TFS are you using? Do you mean you created a project from SSMS and checked in to TFS?